# How to get errors dynamically when typing in fields Formik

Tags: reactjs, formik

**How to get error data dynamically in Formik when entering characters into fields? I get error data only when focus is lost, but I want it right away when I enter the first character.**

```
  const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({

    username: Yup.string()
      .matches(/^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/, "Логин введен некорректно")
      .min(6, "Слишком короткое имя")
      .max(32, "Слишком длинное имя")

      // .minUppercase(1, "password must contain at least 1 upper case letter")

      .required("Обязательное поле"),
    password: Yup.string()
      .required("Обязательное поле")
      .min(6, "Пароль должен содержать минимум шесть символов")
      .max(32, "Слишком длинный пароль")
  });



<Formik
            initialValues={{
             
              username: "",
              password: "",
            }}
            validationSchema={validationSchema}
            onSubmit={registerHandler}
          >
            {({
              isValid,
              dirty,
              isSubmiting,
              handleChange,
              handleBlur,
              values,
              errors,
              touched,
            }) => (
              <Form className={style.form}>
            
               <label>Логин</label>
                <Field
                  type="username"
                  name="username"
                  className={style.input}
                  placeholder={"Введите логин..."}              
                />

                <ErrorMessage
                  validateOnChange={true}
                  name="username"
                  component="div"
                  className={style.error}
                />
                <br />
                <label>Пароль</label>
                <span className={style.pass}>
                  <Field
                    type="password"
                    name="password"
                    className={style.input}
                    placeholder={"Введите пароль..."}
                    innerRef={passRef}
                  />
                 
                  <ErrorMessage
                    name="password"
                    component="div"
                    className={style.error}
                  />
                </span>
```

> Tried to change, add validateOnChange. Changed it to true, *didn't help*
> It seems to me that Formik can somehow keep track of the entered fields dynamically. It shouldn't be hard here